# Eclipse Java application just terminates

Tags: java, eclipse

I have run this application yesterday and went back to work on it more today and when I try to run it, the terminal acts like it's loading and then it just says `Terminated`.

I am using Eclipse Neon, Java version 1.8. The only thing that has changed is that I installed Comodo firewall, but to ensure this wasn't the cause, I disabled all protection and have the same result. I'm the only one working on this project so nobody else has added anything that would cause a crash, there is no error message or exception anyway.

I've right clicked on the main class, `Run as ->Java Application` and no luck.

```
package default_package;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class main
{
  public main() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(main.class);
    logger.info("Application starting");
    if (isFirstRun()) {
        logger.info("Preparing for first run");
        if (setupSumFile()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An unknown error has occured setting up the application for first time use");
            logger.error("Unknown error in main");
            return;
        }
    }
    window w = new window();
  }
  private static boolean isFirstRun() {
      return !(new File("sums.info").exists());
  }
  private static boolean setupSumFile() throws Exception {
      File sumFile = new File("sums.info");
      if(!sumFile.exists()) {
          sumFile.createNewFile();
      }
      return isFirstRun();
  }
}
```

Not even the logger message about the application is getting run.

Edit: Under a suggestion, I tried to run the application in debug mode. While nothing happened and the program instantly terminated, I was able to recieve this error:

`Cannot connect to VM: Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking`

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint and run in debug mode?

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, so `class Main`, not `class main`, and `class Window`, not `class window`, whatever that is.

Comment: This didn't allow my application to run, however it did produce the following error: `Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking`

Comment: I do not know why your initial log does not display, but i think the rest is omitted because you have not removed your `sums.info` file from the first run...

Comment: Also for your second comment, I was taught in school to use camel case, which I suppose stuck with me in all of my naming.

Comment: I removed `sums.info` to try this, same problem.

Comment: Check your Log4J configurations...

Comment: Also loggers should be `private static final`s in the class...

Comment: This was working properly earlier and no changes have been made.

Comment: Socket error likely means that Comodo is blocking Eclipse, so you need to tell Comodo that Eclipse is a **Trusted** application. Try putting Comodo in learning mode (once you read and understand what that means).

Comment: "Cannot connect to VM" is thrown by the debugger...

Comment: This is what I was thinking, however it doesn't have Eclipse listed as a blocked application so I was confused. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about the keywords of the Java. You cannot use those keywords in Class name, variables, method name, etc.

Comment: If you're referring to "window" I can because Java is case sensitive, and it's lower case where the Java keyword is uppercase, "Window". Granted it's not the best solution, but works fine for the small class I created.